# Space-inspired disco clothes, remote-control crystals and an invisible door?

Tags: story-identification

Okay I really need some help here! I loved this movie as a kid, it was my absolute favorite.

It has to be scifi/fantasy maybe 60's/70's/early 80's. I can't acually remember if it was on a planet or a space ship. 
The main things I remember is that the beds had animal fur and the people seemed to dress in "space inspired" disco clothes. Under the fur beds were these crystals that were used a sort of remote controller, and the only other thing I can remember is that there was a woman trapped behind an invisible wall and this man had to save the woman, I think he had the key  but the lock was also invisible....

I hope this is enough!

Comment: Sounds like an episode of Space 1999 are you sure it was a movie?

Comment: @APaleShadow - I seem to recall that the a few of the first episodes of Space 1999 were mashed up together into a TV movie. Maybe that's it?

Comment: I didn't know that, it's certainly a possibility. The furs and crystals is what triggered it for me.

Comment: The man having to save the woman sounds a bit like the episode Space:1999 episode http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_the_Brain - at one point, Koenig and Helena are trapped inside airlocks with the air cycling out; by pressing a button, either of them can save the other at the cost of their own lives... The crystals don't ring any bells, though.

Answer (score 3):

This rings a bell. Could it be *[Barbarella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarella_%28film%29)*, the 1968 film? There is an invisible key involved when Barbarella is trapped in the Tyrant's Chamber of Dreams. There are also some fur beds, and a metric ton of space-disco costumes.